# Visual Studio shows differences when there are none

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diff, tfvc

I am doing a fairly large merge from a branch back to my Trunk.

While doing this I have a lot of "Phantom" changes.  Spots where both files are EXACTLY identical.  Even the white space is the same (as far as I can tell).

**Is there a way to improve Visual Studios diffing abilities to not give me so many false positives?**

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image: Code is the same]

I have "Show Whitespace" turned on (you can see the dot between the `using` and the namespaces), and from what I can see, there is no difference, but visual studio thinks there is.

(NOTE: I tried turning on \ignorewhitespace and it had no effect.)

Comment: Could you make sure  you are merge between branches with a branch-relation (parent child for example) , not perform a baseless merge?

Comment: @patrick-Matt It is parent child. But should that matter if they are the same text?  (FYI: I had trunk->release branch -> subrelease branch. I merged the subrelease back to the release branch and am now merging release branch back to the trunk)

Comment: When you did the baseless merge, every single file in the solution was marked as changed and listed in the pending changes during check in. Did you ever rename one of your branch?

Comment: If you did a **compare** of the branches before you merge , did this "Phantom" change files also listed?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - I did not do a baseless merge.  I merged from the "SubRelease" branch (Child) to the "Release" branch (Parent).  Now I am doing another merge from the "Release" branch (Child) to the trunck (Parent).  (Also, I added an image to show what I am talking about)

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - When I run the compare, the fake differences are not shown... Very confusing.  I wish I could get it to be that smart when merging.

Comment: Have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - this is extremely annoying and time-consuming when I'm doing large merges and I have to eyeball supposed changes to see if something has actually changed. Why can't it just compare the actual text? It's obviously not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the compare, the fake differences are not shown. It means these files are  considered as "different" during the merge process even though they actually not have  changed.

You could double check the **merge status** in the source control explorer. The pending changes window also corroborates this, as all files are listed with a **[merge]** status except those which have actually changed; those have a **[merge, edit]** status.

[image]

There are many possibilities why the "not changed file" still in the pending changes during the merge status. You could double check if the "Phantom" changed files only have a merge status. If so, suggest you ignore it and check in the pending changes directly. For now , it's not able to **filter** TFS merge to only files that have actually changed.

After the merge completed, you could do a compare with the original to see what had been actually changes.